# vim compiled with python3 but python3 omni-completion does not work

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-python

It used to work when I used python2, but now I can't use `^X^O` to complete function names.

I do have vim with `-python` and `+python3` (on Ubuntu 16.04), but here is the error I get when trying Ctrl-X Ctrl-O:

```
Error: Required vim compiled with +python
E117: Unknown function : pythoncomplete#Complete
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I get a working python3-completion in Vim? Thanks a lot.

I don't want to use any completion plugin, since this is supposed to work with normal vim.
I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2084875/4614641), but no answer helps.

**EDIT**:

Checking where omnifunc was defined with `verbose set omnifunc?`, it says
`/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim`

As suggested by @ChristianBrabandt, when I set omnifunc to `python3complete#Complete`, it can complete a few stuff, like `sys.`, but still doesn't work for other modules, e.g argparse. Why is that?

So a temporary fix is to set omnifunc in my `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`, unless anyone has a better suggestion?

Comment: `pythoncomplete#Complete` is for python2, you need to use `python3complete#Complete`. I think you must set either the 'omnifunc' or 'completefunc' option, I can't remember which one

Comment: Ah, you're right, it works better. Still does not complete everything though, so I edited my question.